# Help to identify resistor to remove

Tags: pcb, resistors, pcb-design

I just bought a solar powered LED light that has a motion sensor and a light sensor.
When it is dark, it turns on but very dim. When it detects motion, it turns on full power (not very much...) for 20 seconds, then returns very dim.

What I want to remove is the "very dim" state. I'd prefer it to be off when no motion is detected, so it will save power.
Someone on Amazon (Italy) suggested to remove the R6 resistor, but I discovered I have a newer printed circuit board, so I'm not sure if it is the right resistor (I am no expert in electronics).

Here is the picture of my circuit. Can you tell me if my R6 resistor is the right one to remove?

[image]

**EDIT**

I do not have enough reputation to answer my own question, anyway it worked.

I remove R6 and it worked, now there is bright light for 20 seconds and then nothing. Probably U1 gives a timed output that controls Q2 as suggested by brhans, so R6 is bypassed and the bright light is achieved by the R5.

Thanks!

Comment: We need the schematic.

Comment: If I had to guess I'd say yes R6 probably goes give the 'dim' state, and the 'bright' state is probably achieved when Q2 turns on and bypasses R6.

Comment: try it and see if it works, if it doesn't work you can always put it back on

Comment: What was cut off the board near U4? That looks qukte suspicious there. As for R6, try cutting a 3cm piece of thin copper wire (one of the strands from a piece of "fray wire" lamp cord works great), and solder one end of it to either side of R6, so it forms a "loop" over the resistor. Then, if the light stays full power when it used to stay "very dim," you'll know you have the right resistor to go ahead and remove. If something else happens, just cut the piece of wire & try R5 or R17.

Comment: The answer is indeed yes, removing R6 will disable the "dim" state. If the question gets re-opened, I'll post an answer as to why.

Comment: U3 is some version of the 7136 Constant Current IC. Pin 1, the Current Select, is set by a resistor to ground. R5 and R6, are in series, forming the low brightness current setting. Q2, when enable, shorts R6, meaning R5 sets the brightness by itself, a high brightness. Removing R6 removes the Low Brightness path to ground.

Comment: @TomCarpenter :P You and me both

Comment: Oh, and you can't answer your own question because it was closed, not because of your rep score. Slight difference